# String regular expression java

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm working on a utility where I've this requirement:

1. there is a string which contains parameters like - @p1 or @p2 or @pn, where n can be any number.

for example string is :

Input:

**It provides @p1 latest news, videos @p2 from India and @p3 the world. Get today's news headlines from @p5 Business, @p5**

2. Replace all the parameters with @pn@. So if the parameter is @p1 it will become @p1@.

The above string will become :

Output:

**It provides @p1@ latest news, videos @p2@ from India and @p3@ the world. Get today's news headlines from @p4@ Business, @p5@**

Any quick help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `string.replaceAll` function  like below.

```
string.replaceAll("(@p\\d+)", "$1@");
```

`\d+` matches one or more digits. `()` called capturing group which capture the characters that the matched by the pattern inside `()` and it store the captured characters into their corresponding groups. Later we could refer those characters by specifying its index like `$1` or `$2` .

Example:

```
String s = "It provides @p1 latest news, videos @p2 from India and @p3 the world. Get today's news headlines from @p5 Business, @p5";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(@p\\d+)", "$1@"));
```

Output:

```
It provides @p1@ latest news, videos @p2@ from India and @p3@ the world. Get today's news headlines from @p5@ Business, @p5@
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try regex like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "it provides @p1 latest news, videos @p2 from India and @p3 the world. Get today's news headlines from @p5 Business, @p5";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(@p\\d+)(?=\\s+|$)", "$1\\@"));
}
```

O/P :

```
it provides @p1@ latest news, videos @p2@ from India and @p3@ the world. Get today's news headlines from @p5@ Business, @p5@
```

Explanation :

```
(@p\\d+)(?=\\s+|$) --> `@p` followed by any number of digits (which are all captured) followed by a space or end of String (which are matched but not captured..)
```